# MAAS Issue please help

Tags: juju, maas

When I boot a box via pxe, the booting process start and you can see the OS booting but after a few minutes the screen goes black and shutdown, I can see the machine on my dashboard but like this :

fair-parrot.maas    Unknown     New     0   0.0 0   0.0

regards and thanks 
jc

Comment: no help????????

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behavior.

In MaaS, the first time something PXE boots, it is "enlisted" into the DB.  That involves loading a very small OS that sets up power control if the system has it.  For a VM I get the name, unknown new, 0 cores, 0 RAM, 0 disks, 0 disk space.

The "unknown" supposes you have no capability to power the machine on or off, or check the power state, over the LAN.

Now select the checkbox and you will see a pull-down menu in the upper left change from "Add hardware" to "Take action".  Select this and choose "Commission", and you will see a green button appear "Commission 1 machine" (if you selected one).

Press the green button and then turn your machine on.

It will go through a longer boot cycle.  After the boot cycle, the display will be name, unknown, ready, 4 (cores) 4 (GB ram) 1 (disk) 480 (GB disk space).

Also, I know it can be frustrating, but don't get upset if you don't get same-day answers on askubuntu.  There are times I go in and answer questions that are months to years old because I only just stumbled on them.

Welcome to MaaS and Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much, I realize it yesterday night, but now when I try to commission it, I got this error: **The commission action for 1 node failed with error: Unconfigured power type. Please configure the power type and try again.**

Comment: Good.  Are you also looking at using juju?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRicardo  It is good form to post an answer to your own question when you figure it out.  That way other people stumbling across the same problem see how you solved it.